# Simultaneous Git Pull On Same Server & Directory & User

Tags: git, version-control

We have a staging server that all developers have access too. When they want, they can update the single repo on the staging server (with git pull). Only one unix username on the staging server (uses a deployment key to access remote). Is there a problem on doing that? If two or more users git pull the same repo on the same server as the same user at the same time?

Comment: I think the bigger concern is that your staging server deploys directly using the Git repository...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926391/concurrent-git-pulls-to-same-local-repository

Comment: @JiriKremser I saw that, but there is no trusted answer in that question.

Comment: Using `git fetch` should be safe; using `git pull` is not, in general.  I'm not sure whether to answer this question or the linked one... :-)

Comment: It's okay to do so. When the first user runs git pull, an index.lock is created in .git, thus the other users would fail if they run git pull. The lock file is to be deleted after git pull finishes. In some case, to abort an on-going git command does not delete the lock file properly, which leads to further fail. It will be okay after deleting the lock file. You could have a try in a very big repo in which git pull takes a bit long time.